# Web service to monitor earthquakes in the world

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a good web service to monitor all earthquakes around the world?

It should give the latest earthquake locations on a world map similar to a heat map. It would be nice if we could filter the earthquakes by magnitudes. For example, only list the earthquakes >5M, or only list and sort the ones in Europe, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the official [U.S. Geological Survey Earthquake World map](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/)? There are also maps for various regions, including Europe.

They also offer RSS feeds and KML data.

Answer (score 1):

The [Global Disaster Alert and Coordination System](http://www.gdacs.org/) provides near real-time alerts about natural disasters around the world and tools to facilitate response coordination, including media monitoring, map catalogues and Virtual On-Site Operations Coordination Centre.

For earthquakes -

> GDACS automatically monitors
>   earthquakes. For each earthquake,
>   humanitarian impact is calculated
>   based on magnitude, depth, affected
>   population and their vulnerability and
>   resilience. Detailed reports with
>   affected infrastructure are available.
>   Each 15 minutes, GDACS collects - in
>   an automatic way - media reports,
>   damage maps, ReliefWeb situation
>   reports and more about the
>   earthquakes.

[GDACS Earthquakes page](http://w3.gdacs.org/earthquakes/) gives information on all the earthquakes in the form of markers on Google Maps and also as a table. Search feature is also provided to filter earthquakes according to country, alert level, affected population etc.